# camlzip: "This package relies on external (system) dependencies that may be missing."

Tags: ocaml, opam

I'm trying to install camlzip (an OCaml package housed in opam), but when I run `opam install camlzip` I get this:

```
The following actions will be performed:
  ∗  install camlzip 1.05

=-=- Gathering sources =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[camlzip] Archive in cache

=-=- Processing actions -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[ERROR] The compilation of camlzip failed at "make all".
Processing  1/1: [camlzip: ocamlfind remove]
#=== ERROR while installing camlzip.1.05 ======================================#
# opam-version 1.2.2
# os           linux
# command      make all
# path         /home/mttjone/.opam/system/build/camlzip.1.05
# compiler     system (4.02.3)
# exit-code    2
# env-file     /home/mttjone/.opam/system/build/camlzip.1.05/camlzip-3552-d2d111.env
# stdout-file  /home/mttjone/.opam/system/build/camlzip.1.05/camlzip-3552-d2d111.out
# stderr-file  /home/mttjone/.opam/system/build/camlzip.1.05/camlzip-3552-d2d111.err
### stdout ###
# ocamlc -g -c -ccopt -g -ccopt -I/usr/local/include zlibstubs.c
### stderr ###
# [...]
# zlibstubs.c:151: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
# zlibstubs.c: In function ‘camlzip_inflateEnd’:
# zlibstubs.c:165: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘inflateEnd’
# zlibstubs.c:165: error: ‘z_stream’ undeclared (first use in this function)
# zlibstubs.c:165: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
# zlibstubs.c:165: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int *’ and ‘int *’)
# zlibstubs.c:165: error: called object ‘<erroneous-expression>’ is not a function
# zlibstubs.c: In function ‘camlzip_update_crc32’:
# zlibstubs.c:172: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘crc32’
# make: *** [zlibstubs.o] Error 2



=-=- Error report -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
The following actions failed
  ∗  install camlzip 1.05
No changes have been performed

=-=- camlzip.1.05 troobleshooting -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
=> This package relies on external (system) dependencies that may be missing. `opam depext camlzip.1.05' may help you find the correct installation for your system.
```

Now I think it's clear the it isn't acctually missing dependencies, but I can the suggested command anyway and it said I wasn't missing any dependencies.

Presumably the problem is with the `zlibstubs.c` file, but I'm not exactly sure what's happening.

Can anyone hep me out?

Comment: You may be missing a lib on your system (not an ocaml lib, but a system lib)

Comment: You are correct, for some reason the machines they give up don't have zlib.

Comment: do `opam source camlzip` and look at the opam file at the bottom, youll see `depexts:[...` those are the respective system libraries needed. You can use `opam depext` for this but i forgot the exact command

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
opam install depext
opam depext camlzip
```

### Explanations

The `opam install depext` command will install an `opam` plugin that is capable of installing external dependencies. It will add a `depext` command to `opam` tool.

The `opam depext camlzip` will install external dependencies, using system package manager. If your package manager is not supported, then the command will fail. In that case you can use

```
opam list --external --required-by=camlzip
```

to get all external dependencies of `camlzip` for all distributions and package management systems known to a package maintainer. From this information you can infer the names of packages for your distribution. Once you succeed, it is also a good idea to contribute this information back to the maintainer.