# Installing zlib outside of the normal directory

Tags: ocaml, build-process, opam

I'm trying to install a package which depends on camlzip (an OCaml package provided my opam). This package depends on zlib, I know this because I tried before and ran into the same error [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135963/camlzip-this-package-relies-on-external-system-dependencies-that-may-be-miss).

The issue is that when I install zlib to `$PKG_DIR/sw` by running `./configure --prefix=$PKG_DIR/sw` I get the same error suggesting that zlib isn't installed. (I have of course add $PKG_DIR/sw to the PATH)

I'm a bit new to Linux, and I'm probably missing an environment variable but I have no idea what. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid it's corporate system based on RHEL5. It's probably most similar to Amazon Linux.

Comment: why not to install zlib-devel to "normal" directory? I guess, you can install it from rpm package http://serverfault.com/questions/608781/is-there-a-way-to-install-pip-and-zlib-devel-on-rhel-5-7-without-red-hat-entitle

Comment: Because it needs to be run as root to install to it's normal directory, and I would really like to avoid that.

I've tried installing form source, rpm, and .src.rpm, but opam seems to specifically look it the default directory.

Comment: so, you successfully installed zlib, but it is not visible by OPAM, right? Make sure C_INCLUDE_PATH contains path to zlib header files (*.h), and LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains path to zlib library files (*.a).